# Amazon Affiliate Program: Can you land on a search results page with your tag?

Tags: amazon-product-api, affiliate

For example, from my website I want to link users to an entire search queries result page on Amazon.com rather than thinking them to just one specific product at a time.

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
http://www.amazon.com/s/?ref=sr_st?keywords=skates&qid=1363145953&rh=n:3375251,k:skates&sort=-price&tag=stackexample-20
```

[Go to link shown above](http://www.amazon.com/s/?ref=sr_st?keywords=skates&qid=1363145953&rh=n:3375251,k%3askates&sort=-price&tag=stackexample-20)

As you can see I'm trying to land users on a search page for "skates", with the highest priced items at the top, and my affiliate ID in this case "stackexample-20"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know that is old question, but did you find out this thing? I think that you can add tag to search ling, but cookie is created only in product detail with tag.

Comment: @tomasr search page tagging works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

**2018:** You could create a link like this (using jquery):

```
      function createAmznLink (text) {        
         var amznLink = "<a href=http://www.amazon.de/s/field-keywords=" + text + "&tag=yourtag" + ">" + text + "</a>"              
         $('.linklist').append(amznLink);        
      }

      createAmznLink('product');
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do searches using affiliate tags you are doing it above once you are on the page you will get commissions for the next 24 hours(i think) . Since the affiliate cookie is set on the browser of the user.

Comment: Sorry, but "I think" doesn't really cut it as a valid answer here. I know how the affiliate program and cookies that get on the client work. What I'd like to see is someone actually verify earnings from doing this.